# How does MATLAB read and interpret binary digits from a .bin file?

Tags: matlab, binary

I have a binary file with .bin extension. This file is created by a data acquisition software. Basically a "measurement computing" 16-bit data-acquisition hardware is receiving signals from a transducer(after amplified by an amplifier) and sending this to PC by a USB. A program/software then is generating a .bin file corresponding received serial data from data aq. hardware. There are several ways to read this .bin file and plot the signal in MATLAB.

When I open this .bin file with a hexeditor I can see the ASCII or ones and zeros (binary). The thing is I don't know how to interpret this knowledge. There are 208000 bytes in the file obtained in 16 seconds. I was thinking each 2 bytes corresponds to a sample since the DAQ device has 16 bit resolution. So I thought for example a 16-bit data such as 1000100111110010 is converted by MATLAB to a corresponding voltage level. But I tried to open two different .bin files with different voltage levels such as 1V and 9V and still teh numbers do not seem to be related what I think.

How does MATLAB read and interpret binary digits from a .bin file?

Thnx,

Comment: The extention .bin, like .dat, is rather meaningless and tells you little, if anything at all, about the format of the content. What software did you use to capture this data? What sample rate was it acquired at? Also, was it *exactly* 16 seconds of data you acquired? If so, then with the sample rate you can figure out if the data has some format specification or is literally just a dump of the values.

Comment: I don't remember the sampling rate. The program is written by an engineer in Delphi language. It is not a commercial one. It took me 16 seconds for each acquisition.  Then I opened the file in hexeditor and saw bin has 208000 bytes of data so I thought it means 104000 16-bit chunks and 104000/16sec = 6500 samples/sec since each sample has 16 bit depth. I'm not sure about my knowledge here. How can I know how thesebinary digits are interpreted by MATLAB? There is just 1 or 2 page written in 900 page MATLAB book about this issue. I couldn find any tutuorial where I can learn how it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your .bin file is literally just a dump of the values recorded, you can read the data using `fread` (see [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) for more info):

```
fid = fopen('path_to_your_file', 'r');
nSamples = 104000;
data = fread(fid, nSamples, 'int16');
fclose(fid);
```

You will also need to know, however, whether this data is signed or unsigned - if it's unsigned you can use `'uint16'` as the third argument to `fread` instead. You should also find out if it's big-endian or little-endian... You should check the original program's source code.

It's a good idea to record the sample rate at which you make acquisitions like this, because you'll be hard pressed to do anything but trivial analysis on it afterwards without knowing this information. Often this kind of data is stored in .wav files, so that both the data and its sample rate (and the bit depth, in fact) are stored in the file. That way you don't need a separate bit of paper to go along with your file (also, reading .wav files in MATLAB is extremely easy).

Comment: it iS not wav. it is a .bin file BIN

Comment: The code I provided should work for your .bin file format. The stuff about .wav files is just general advice.